# VB.net How to make all the borderless forms of a project use the same common code given below to move the form without repetation?

Tags: vb.net, forms, move, borderless

This code i found i stackoverflow to move a borderless form in vb.net. I want to implement it for all the 10 forms of my project and don't want to put it in every form's code. Is there a way to use the single instance of this code for all forms? Thanks

```
Public Sub MoveForm_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown

    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        MoveForm = True
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.NoMove2D
        MoveForm_MousePosition = e.Location
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub MoveForm_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove

    If MoveForm Then
        Me.Location = Me.Location + (e.Location - MoveForm_MousePosition)
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub MoveForm_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp

    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        MoveForm = False
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a derived class representing a borderless, movable form. Let this class inherit from the standard `Form` control and add in any additional functionality that you need. Use this new class instead of the standard `Form` when building forms.

```
Public Class MovableForm
    Inherits Form

Private MoveForm As Boolean
Private MoveForm_MousePosition As Point

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(e As MouseEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseDown(e)

    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        MoveForm = True
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.NoMove2D
        MoveForm_MousePosition = e.Location
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(e As MouseEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseMove(e)

    If MoveForm Then
        Me.Location += e.Location - MoveForm_MousePosition
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseUp(e As MouseEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseUp(e)

    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        MoveForm = False
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Then to use it change the designer file of your form like this:

```
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits BorderlessForm
```

Comment: You have the right idea, but if you "consume" the event in the base class then it is not appropriate to call the MyBase method.